The Assumptions in Kunen's $\Delta$ System Lemma Proof
I have a question when reading Kunen's Set Theory: An Independence Proof, Chapter II, Theorem 1.6.

Let $\kappa$ be any infinite cardinal. Let $\theta>\kappa$ be regular and satisfy $\forall \alpha<\theta\left(\left|\alpha^{<\kappa}\right|<\theta\right)$. Assume $|\mathscr A|\ge\theta$ and $\forall x \in \mathscr A(|x|<\kappa)$, then there is a $\mathscr B\subset \mathscr A$, such that $|\mathscr B|=\theta$ and $\mathscr B$ forms a $\Delta$-system.
Proof. By shrinking $\mathscr A$ if necessary, we may assume $|\mathscr A|=\theta$. Then $\backslash \mathscr A\mid \le\theta$. Since what the elements of $\mathscr A$ are as individuals is irrelevant, we may assume $\bigcup_{\mathscr A} \subset \theta$. Then each $x \in \mathscr A$ has some order type $<\kappa$ as a subset of $\theta$. Since $\theta$ is regular and $\theta>\kappa$, there is some $\rho<\kappa$, such that $\mathscr A_1=$ $\{x \in \mathscr A: x$ has type $\rho\}$ has cardinality $\theta$. We now fix such a $\rho$ and deal only with $\mathscr A_1$.
For each $\alpha<\theta,\left|\alpha^{<\kappa}\right|<\theta$ implies that less than $\theta$ elements of $\mathscr A_1$ are subsets of $\alpha$. Thus, $\bigcup \mathscr A_1$ is unbounded in $\theta$. If $x \in \mathscr a_1$ and $\xi<\rho$, let $x(\xi)$ be the $\xi$-th element of $x$. Since $\theta$ is regular, there is some $\xi$ such that $\left\{x(\xi): x \in \mathscr A_1\right\}$ is unbounded in $\theta$. Now fix $\xi_0$ to be the least such $\xi\left(\xi_0\right.$ may be 0 ). Let
$$
\alpha_0=\sup \left\{x(\eta)+1: x \in \mathscr A_1 \land \eta<\xi_0\right\}
$$
then $\alpha_0<\theta$ and $x(\eta)<\alpha_0$ for all $x \in \mathscr A_1$ and all $\eta<\xi_0$.
By transfinite recursion on $\mu<\theta$, pick $x_\mu \in \mathscr A_1$ so that $x_\mu\left(\xi_0\right)>\alpha_0$ and $x_\mu\left(\xi_0\right)$ is above all elements of earlier $x_v$; i.e.,
$$
x_\mu\left(\xi_0\right)>\max \left(\alpha_0, \sup \left\{x_v(\eta): \eta<\rho \land v<\mu\right\}\right) .
$$
Let $\mathscr A_2=\left\{x_\mu: \mu<\theta\right\}$. Then $\left|\mathscr A_2\right|=\theta$ and $x \cap y \subset \alpha_0$ whenever $x$ and $y$ are distinct elements of $\mathscr A_2$. Since $\left|\alpha_0^{<\kappa}\right|<\theta$, there is an $r \subset \alpha_0$ and a $\mathscr b\subset \mathscr A_2$ with $|\mathscr B|=\theta$ and $\forall x \in \mathscr B\left(x \cap \alpha_0=r\right)$, whence $\mathscr B$ forms a $\Delta$-system with root $r$.

Why can we assume that $\bigcup \mathcal{A} \subset \theta$? In the following proof, it assumes $x$ is a subset of $\theta$ and $x(\xi)$ is an ordinal, but is that always true?
Why can't $x(\xi)$ not be an ordinal?
If we use the cardinality of $x(\xi)$ instead of assuming $x$ is a subset of $\theta$, then there is a question that $|x(\xi)| > \theta$.
Thanks!

I've answered the question, but it's generally considered (at best) poor form to use an image as an important part of a question (or answer).  Among other things, images can't be searched, and can't always be seen by some users of the site.  I understand that it's a pain to do so, but the correct protocol here is to retype the question.  Would you please do so?

We can assume $\mathscr A \subseteq \theta$ because$\vert \bigcup \mathscr A \vert \leq \theta$, so there is an injective map $f: \bigcup \mathscr A \to \theta$.  Work with the $f$-image of all sets in the proof and you are working within $\theta$.
Since (under this identification) $x \subseteq \theta$, each element of $x$ is an ordinal.

Thank you for your response! I have clarified my doubts. I understand that one can obtain an injection from $\cup \mathscr{A}$ to . However, what I'm not entirely clear about is that in the later proof, it uses the properties of ordinals, and I'm not sure if these properties are indeed preserved under this injection. I now understand that they can be preserved. Thank you.
